# Inherting values friom one object to another

Tags: java

i have this code here.Tuple is a class using (int,int) as keys to find a specific object.I have overrided hashcode and equals because if i have a specific (x,y) value i want to be able to compare it.

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.Queue; 
import java.util.*;


class Tuple {
      public Tuple (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      }
      public String moves;
     public int  times;
      public int getX(){
            return this.x;

        }
        public int getY(){
            return this.y;

        }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 5 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 5 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }
      @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) { 
            if (o == this) { 
                return true; 
            }   
            if (!(o instanceof Tuple)) { 
                return false; 
            } 
            Tuple c = (Tuple) o; 
            return Double.compare(x, c.x) == 0
                    && Double.compare(y, c.y) == 0; 
        } 
      private int x;
      private int y;
    }




public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Tuple t2=new Tuple(1,1);
    t2.moves="aaa";

    Tuple t1=new Tuple(1,1);
    System.out.print(t1.moves);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to inherit t1.moves to t2.moves without knowing the actual t1 object and only by having (1,1)?Should String moves be public in order to achieve that?

Comment: Never separate your class variables like this, always put them at the top of the class for clarity, writing it this way makes it extremely confusing and convoluted.

Comment: Maybe you mean `t1.moves = t2.moves;`?

Comment: Can you edit in expected output?  I don't understand what you are trying to do exactly.  I assume it is something like what @Avi said as well, but it is not written clearly.

Comment: suppose i don't know t1 and i only have (t1.x,t1.y).

Comment: How do you access `t1.x` and `t1.y` if you don't know `t1`?

Comment: This is a solid reason for using getters and setters instead of direct field access.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly then `t1` and `t2` are two objects of the same class. As such scenario where `t2`  inherits data from `t1` does not arise.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a `Key` of two numbers to return a `String`, from the way you wrote your question.  To do this you can use a `Map` and relate it to your two numbers somehow.

The *best* way to do this is most likely to write your own wrapper class on an `int[]` and override the `hashcode` and the `equals`.  In your code you would basically have to separate your code into the `Class` that implements this idea, and the `Class` that contains the `map`.

Below I did it without implementing my own wrapper class by using `Arrays.toString()` as the `key` instead of the actual array.  You can use this as a base to use the Array wrapper class if you want to modify it.

Below is the fully functional code that does not use the wrapper class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Tuple {

    private Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public Tuple() {
    }

    public String get(int x, int y) {
        return map.get(Arrays.toString(new int[] {x,y}));
    }

    public void put(int x, int y, String str) {
        this.map.put(Arrays.toString(new int[] {x,y}), str);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    
        Tuple tup = new Tuple();
    
        tup.put(1, 1, "I am 1 1!");
        tup.put(2, 3, "I am 2 3!");
        tup.put(4, 4, "I am 4 4!");
    
        System.out.println(tup.get(1,1));
        System.out.println(tup.get(2,3));
        System.out.println(tup.get(4,4));
        System.out.println(tup.get(3,2)); //Does not exist
    }



}
```

**Output:**

> I am 1 1!
>
> I am 2 3!
>
> I am 4 4!
>
> null

This code uses a custom `put` that takes input as `int, int, String` to create the `<Key, Value>` and store it into the `Map`.

It also has a `get(int, int)` that you can use when you need to get the original `String` back.  Keep in mind `(x, y)` is NOT the same as `(y, x)`.

Also I recommend using setters and getters and making your class variables `private` rather than making them public.

**EDIT:**

Here is a way to do it with your current code by removing `String` from inside `Tuple` and using it as the `Map` value and using your current hash implementation:

```
class Tuple {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int times;

    public Tuple (int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 17;
      hash = 5 * hash + this.x;
      hash = 5 * hash + this.y;
      return hash;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) { 
        if (o == this) { 
            return true; 
        }   
        if (!(o instanceof Tuple)) { 
            return false; 
        } 
        Tuple c = (Tuple) o; 
        return Double.compare(x, c.x) == 0
              && Double.compare(y, c.y) == 0; 
    } 


    public static void main(String [] args) {
    
        Map<Tuple,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    
        Tuple tup1 = new Tuple(1, 1);
        Tuple tup2 = new Tuple(2, 2);
        Tuple tup3 = new Tuple(3, 4);
        map.put(tup1, "aaa");
        map.put(tup2, "bbbb");
        map.put(tup3, "dddddd");
    
        System.out.println(map.get(new Tuple(1, 1)));
        System.out.println(map.get(new Tuple(2, 2)));
        System.out.println(map.get(new Tuple(3, 4)));
        System.out.println(map.get(new Tuple(4, 3))); //Prints null

        //OR LIKE YOUR EXAMPLE CASE
        Tuple tup4 = new Tuple(1, 1);
        System.out.println(map.get(tup4));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

> aaa
>
> bbbb
>
> dddddd
>
> null
>
> aaa

Ideally you would use a `Class` to wrap this `Map` in like my original method so you would not need to use `new Tuple(1, 1)` to get the `String` back as you can make a method inside that does that for you with input of `int, int`.